# Is there a class in Android for formatting Cookies into the value for a CookieManager?

Tags: java, android, cookies, setcookie

When my app starts up, I post a login request to a web service and receive a Cookie.  I want to use that Cookie in my WebView, which I do with the following code:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = this.get_my_cookies_from_somewhere();
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    String rawUrl = (cookie.isSecure() ? "https" : "http") + "://" + cookie.getDomain() + cookie.getPath();
    cookieManager.setCookie(rawUrl, cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + cookie.getDomain());
}
cookieSyncManager.sync();
```

Ideally, I would like to have the cookie url and "Set-Cookie" header value required by the CookieManager be built by the Cookie class or some utility class.  Does such a thing exist?

I tried RFC2109Spec and RFC2965Spec, but they produce the "Cookie" header, not the "Set-Cookie" header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred method appears to be to send the Headers from your Response directly to the CookieManager.  I'm basing this on [code I found from Romain Guy](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/util/CookieStore.java):

```
final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
final HttpResponse response = ...
final Header[] cookies = response.getHeaders("set-cookie");
for (Header cooky : cookies) {
    cookieManager.setCookie(url, cooky.getValue());
}
```